# How to force check out on SharePoint search results?

Tags: 2010, search, document, check-out

When get search results with documents and I click on it to edit they are not checked out. Despite the fact that I activated check-in/check-out in the DL where the document is located. How can I force checkout on the search results page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the office 2010 applications check out will be forced after a document has been opened (not with the standard dialog after clicking a document in a document library). There is a yellow bar under the ribbon which says "check out required".

Not sure what the behavior is with older office versions and non-office documents/apps.